Encountering ModuleNotFoundError for mask2former after successful installation and dependency setup
When I using this instructions from text to install Mask2Former.
And I'm pretty sure detectron2 has been installed successfully.
git clone git@github.com:facebookresearch/Mask2Former.git
cd Mask2Former
pip install -r requirements.txt
cd mask2former/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops
sh make.sh

But I got this log, in the last.
Installed /home/lab-602/anaconda3/envs/mask2former/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MultiScaleDeformableAttention-1.0-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for MultiScaleDeformableAttention==1.0
Finished processing dependencies for MultiScaleDeformableAttention==1.0

It seems I already successful install the dependencies MultiScaleDeformableAttention==1.0 for Mask2Former.
But when I try improt mask2former, it still "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mask2former'"
I dont know hot to deal with it.
My environment
Python 3.9.19
CUDA 12.5
absl-py                       2.1.0
antlr4-python3-runtime        4.9.3
black                         24.4.2
certifi                       2024.7.4
charset-normalizer            3.3.2
click                         8.1.7
cloudpickle                   3.0.0
contourpy                     1.2.1
cycler                        0.12.1
Cython                        3.0.10
detectron2                    0.6                /home/lab-602/detectron2
filelock                      3.15.4
fonttools                     4.53.1
fsspec                        2024.6.1
fvcore                        0.1.5.post20221221
grpcio                        1.65.1
h5py                          3.11.0
huggingface-hub               0.24.0
hydra-core                    1.3.2
idna                          3.7
imageio                       2.34.2
importlib_metadata            8.0.0
importlib_resources           6.4.0
iopath                        0.1.9
Jinja2                        3.1.4
kiwisolver                    1.4.5
lazy_loader                   0.4
Markdown                      3.6
MarkupSafe                    2.1.5
matplotlib                    3.9.1
mpmath                        1.3.0
MultiScaleDeformableAttention 1.0
mypy-extensions               1.0.0
networkx                      3.2.1
ninja                         1.11.1.1
numpy                         2.0.0
nvidia-cublas-cu12            12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12        12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12        12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12      12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12             8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12             11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12            10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12          11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12          12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12              2.20.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12         12.5.82
nvidia-nvtx-cu12              12.1.105
omegaconf                     2.3.0
opencv-python                 4.10.0.84
packaging                     24.1
pathspec                      0.12.1
pillow                        10.4.0
pip                           24.0
platformdirs                  4.2.2
portalocker                   2.10.1
protobuf                      4.25.3
pycocotools                   2.0.8
pyparsing                     3.1.2
python-dateutil               2.9.0.post0
PyYAML                        6.0.1
requests                      2.32.3
safetensors                   0.4.3
scikit-image                  0.24.0
scipy                         1.13.1
setuptools                    69.5.1
shapely                       2.0.5
six                           1.16.0
submitit                      1.5.1
sympy                         1.13.0
tabulate                      0.9.0
tensorboard                   2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.2
termcolor                     2.4.0
tifffile                      2024.7.2
timm                          1.0.7
tomli                         2.0.1
torch                         2.3.1
torchaudio                    2.3.1
torchvision                   0.18.1
tqdm                          4.66.4
triton                        2.3.1
typing_extensions             4.12.2
urllib3                       2.2.2
Werkzeug                      3.0.3
wheel                         0.43.0
yacs                          0.1.8
zipp                          3.19.2


To import mask2former with import mask2former you first need to install mask2former as a package. Add the setup.py file in the root directory of the Mask2Former repo. Then write these instructions in the setup.py file:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
   name='mask2former',
   version='1.0',
   description='Mask2former package',
   packages=find_packages(),
)

Finally, you have to create an empty __init__.py file in the directory Mask2Former/mask2former/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops.
If you have followed the Mask2Former installation instructions you should have already launched these two commands:
cd mask2former/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops
sh make.sh

If not, do this now. Then go in the Mask2Former directory and run the command:
python setup.py install

